# TFS Code Coverage out by 0.1

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have an intermittent issue on our TFS 2012 build server against a mature enterprise product.

Occasionally the gated builds fail because the code coverage reported by TFS has decreased by 0.1 when no code has changed or non-testable code such as css has changed.

Any ideas on why this happens or mitigating steps?

Currently updating build to lower code coverage and are planning to add a .1 fudge factor.